# Awk print record before or after a matching string

Tags: linux, awk, bioinformatics, fasta

I have lots of FASTA files containing gene annotations and sequences. One of the genes I am interested in is `CadC`. What I also want to look at are the genes that are around `CadC`, they may be listed as hypothetical proteins or another name entirely. Here is an example of the layout:

```
>CPMPPENI_00027 hypothetical protein
ATGATAAATACAATAATTACTGGAATAATTCTTTATGCAGGAACTGCAGTTGATTTAATA
ATTATTTTAATGATATTTTTTGCTAAGCTAAAAAAGAAAGATGAAATTAGACAAATTTAT
TTAGGACAATTTCTTGGATCTGGATTTCTAATTTTTTTAAGCATGATTTTCGCATATCTT
CTCCATTTTGTACCCAATAAAGAACTTTTAGGGTTATTAGGTTTAGTTCCAATTTTTTTG
GGTCTAAAAGTACTTTTAGGTGGCGAAGAGGGTGGCGAGGAATTGGCAAATGAACGCCTA
GAACAGCCTAAAAAGATCAATATCGTTTATACTTTAGCTATGATCACAGCAGTAAGTTGT
GGAGCTGATAATATTGGGTTGTTTGTTCCTTATTTCATAACTTTAAATTTTCAAAAACTA
ATTGTAACTTTAATTACTTTCTTTGTTATGATTTTCTTGCTGGTTTATTCGGCACAAAAA
ATAGTTAACTTACCAAAAATCGGAGAATTCTTAGAAAAAAATAGTAGGTGGTTTATTTCA
ATAGTATATATTGTTTTAGGTATATTCATCCTAATTGAAAATAACTCCATTGAATTATTT
AAAACCCTATTTTAA

>CPMPPENI_00028 Cadmium resistance transcriptional regulatory protein CadC
ATGACTAAAGAATTAATTTGCGAAAATATTGTAATCGAAGAAGAAAAAGTTAACAGAGTG
TTAGATTATTTTGAAATGGATTCTTCTAAAAGGTATTTGAGAATACTTTCAAAAATAAGT
GATGAAAAGAAAGTAAAAATAATACTATCACTAATAAAAGAAGAAAAACTTTGTGTTTGT
GATGTAGCCTTTCTTCTAAATATTAGTATAGCTTCAGCGTCACATCATTTACGAAAGTTA
TATAAACAAGATGTTTTAGATTTTTCCAAAGACGGTAAAATGGTTTACTATTTTATAAAA
GATGATGAAATAAAAGATTTTTTCTCATAA

>CPMPPENI_00029 hypothetical protein
ATGAGGTTTGCTATGCATTGGGAAGTTTTAACGATGACAAAATCAAAACGTTGGAGACCT
GTTCCAACCGTTACTAAATTTGACACAGAGCAAGAAGCTATAGACTTTAAAAACTCTCTT
AAACAATATTGTGAACTTTACCAAGTTAATGGTTAA
```

I have been using this code to print the `CadC` header and sequence:

```
awk -vRS='>' '$2~/Cadmium/ {print RS FILENAME "|" $0}' file.ffn > cadc.txt
```

This gives me this output:

```
>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00028 Cadmium resistance transcriptional regulatory protein CadC
ATGACTAAAGAATTAATTTGCGAAAATATTGTAATCGAAGAAGAAAAAGTTAACAGAGTG
TTAGATTATTTTGAAATGGATTCTTCTAAAAGGTATTTGAGAATACTTTCAAAAATAAGT
GATGAAAAGAAAGTAAAAATAATACTATCACTAATAAAAGAAGAAAAACTTTGTGTTTGT
GATGTAGCCTTTCTTCTAAATATTAGTATAGCTTCAGCGTCACATCATTTACGAAAGTTA
TATAAACAAGATGTTTTAGATTTTTCCAAAGACGGTAAAATGGTTTACTATTTTATAAAA
GATGATGAAATAAAAGATTTTTTCTCATAA
```

What I would like to do is also print the gene preceding `CadC` and/or the gene following `CadC` so that the output would look like this:

```
>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00027 hypothetical protein
ATGATAAATACAATAATTACTGGAATAATTCTTTATGCAGGAACTGCAGTTGATTTAATA
ATTATTTTAATGATATTTTTTGCTAAGCTAAAAAAGAAAGATGAAATTAGACAAATTTAT
TTAGGACAATTTCTTGGATCTGGATTTCTAATTTTTTTAAGCATGATTTTCGCATATCTT
CTCCATTTTGTACCCAATAAAGAACTTTTAGGGTTATTAGGTTTAGTTCCAATTTTTTTG
GGTCTAAAAGTACTTTTAGGTGGCGAAGAGGGTGGCGAGGAATTGGCAAATGAACGCCTA
GAACAGCCTAAAAAGATCAATATCGTTTATACTTTAGCTATGATCACAGCAGTAAGTTGT
GGAGCTGATAATATTGGGTTGTTTGTTCCTTATTTCATAACTTTAAATTTTCAAAAACTA
ATTGTAACTTTAATTACTTTCTTTGTTATGATTTTCTTGCTGGTTTATTCGGCACAAAAA
ATAGTTAACTTACCAAAAATCGGAGAATTCTTAGAAAAAAATAGTAGGTGGTTTATTTCA
ATAGTATATATTGTTTTAGGTATATTCATCCTAATTGAAAATAACTCCATTGAATTATTT
AAAACCCTATTTTAA

>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00028 Cadmium resistance transcriptional regulatory protein CadC
ATGACTAAAGAATTAATTTGCGAAAATATTGTAATCGAAGAAGAAAAAGTTAACAGAGTG
TTAGATTATTTTGAAATGGATTCTTCTAAAAGGTATTTGAGAATACTTTCAAAAATAAGT
GATGAAAAGAAAGTAAAAATAATACTATCACTAATAAAAGAAGAAAAACTTTGTGTTTGT
GATGTAGCCTTTCTTCTAAATATTAGTATAGCTTCAGCGTCACATCATTTACGAAAGTTA
TATAAACAAGATGTTTTAGATTTTTCCAAAGACGGTAAAATGGTTTACTATTTTATAAAA
GATGATGAAATAAAAGATTTTTTCTCATAA

>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00029 hypothetical protein
ATGAGGTTTGCTATGCATTGGGAAGTTTTAACGATGACAAAATCAAAACGTTGGAGACCT
GTTCCAACCGTTACTAAATTTGACACAGAGCAAGAAGCTATAGACTTTAAAAACTCTCTT
AAACAATATTGTGAACTTTACCAAGTTAATGGTTAA
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Are entries between `>` separated by empty lines? Btw, you should escape `>`, otherwise they're interpreted as quote block.

Comment: @AndreWildberg Maybe in this specific case of the OP, they are separated, but this may not always be the case. The headers always start with `>`.

Comment: What should the output look like if back-to-back records contain `CadC`?

Comment: Thank you, i'll make sure to use that in future! That's a good question regarding back to back CadC entries, I hadn't considered it because it's very unlikely. But if so, I would want both CadC entries and then the entries before and after.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample input/output with [that case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75826822/awk-print-record-before-or-after-a-matching-string/75828949#comment133757983_75826822) to demonstrate [that requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75826822/awk-print-record-before-or-after-a-matching-string/75828949#comment133762190_75826822) and give us something to copy/paste to test with.

Answer (score 4):

Do not reinvent the wheel. For common bioinformatics tasks, use open-source tools that are specifically designed for these tasks, are well-tested, widely used, and handle edge cases.

Use `grep -C1` to write to a temp file the sequence ids of the genes within +/-1 of your gene. Then use `seqtk` toolkit to select from your fasta file only those sequences whose ids are listed in the temp file.

To extract reads from fastq files by IDs, use [`seqtk subseq`](https://github.com/lh3/seqtk).

```
grep '^>' in.fa | sed 's/^>//' | grep -C1 'CadC' | cut -d' ' -f1 > names.txt

seqtk subseq in.fa names.txt > out.fa
```

`grep '^>' in.fa` : select all fasta headers = lines that start with `>`.
`sed 's/^>//'` : remove the `>` at the start of the line.
`grep -C1 'CadC'` : select the line with you gene (`CadC`), and 1 line before and after it. Use any number `N` instead of 1 to select `N` neighbors.
`cut -d' ' -f1` : cut the first field, delimited by spaces. This is the sequence id, which `seqtk subseq` needs as input.

To install `seqtk`, use `conda`, specifically `miniconda`, for example:

```
conda create --channel bioconda --name seqtk seqtk
conda activate seqtk
# ... use seqtk here ...
conda deactivate
```

**References:**

`seqtk`: https://github.com/lh3/seqtk
`conda`: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html
`conda create`: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html

**See also:**
[Extracting specific sequences from FASTQ using Seqtk](https://www.biostars.org/p/342043/)
[How To Extracting Fastq Sequence For Given Fastq Ids And Fastq File](https://www.biostars.org/p/74243/)
[How To Extract A Subset Of Reads In Fastq Using An Id List?](https://www.biostars.org/p/45816/)

Comment: Not only was my (deleted) idea buggy, this is just better all over :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' -v OFS='|' '
    $1 ~ /CadC/ { if (!f) prt(prev); prt($0); f=1; next }
    f { prt($0); f=0 }
    { prev=$0 }
    function prt(rec) { sub(/^>/,"",rec); print ">" FILENAME, rec }
' file.ffn
>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00027 hypothetical protein
ATGATAAATACAATAATTACTGGAATAATTCTTTATGCAGGAACTGCAGTTGATTTAATA
ATTATTTTAATGATATTTTTTGCTAAGCTAAAAAAGAAAGATGAAATTAGACAAATTTAT
TTAGGACAATTTCTTGGATCTGGATTTCTAATTTTTTTAAGCATGATTTTCGCATATCTT
CTCCATTTTGTACCCAATAAAGAACTTTTAGGGTTATTAGGTTTAGTTCCAATTTTTTTG
GGTCTAAAAGTACTTTTAGGTGGCGAAGAGGGTGGCGAGGAATTGGCAAATGAACGCCTA
GAACAGCCTAAAAAGATCAATATCGTTTATACTTTAGCTATGATCACAGCAGTAAGTTGT
GGAGCTGATAATATTGGGTTGTTTGTTCCTTATTTCATAACTTTAAATTTTCAAAAACTA
ATTGTAACTTTAATTACTTTCTTTGTTATGATTTTCTTGCTGGTTTATTCGGCACAAAAA
ATAGTTAACTTACCAAAAATCGGAGAATTCTTAGAAAAAAATAGTAGGTGGTTTATTTCA
ATAGTATATATTGTTTTAGGTATATTCATCCTAATTGAAAATAACTCCATTGAATTATTT
AAAACCCTATTTTAA

>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00028 Cadmium resistance transcriptional regulatory protein CadC
ATGACTAAAGAATTAATTTGCGAAAATATTGTAATCGAAGAAGAAAAAGTTAACAGAGTG
TTAGATTATTTTGAAATGGATTCTTCTAAAAGGTATTTGAGAATACTTTCAAAAATAAGT
GATGAAAAGAAAGTAAAAATAATACTATCACTAATAAAAGAAGAAAAACTTTGTGTTTGT
GATGTAGCCTTTCTTCTAAATATTAGTATAGCTTCAGCGTCACATCATTTACGAAAGTTA
TATAAACAAGATGTTTTAGATTTTTCCAAAGACGGTAAAATGGTTTACTATTTTATAAAA
GATGATGAAATAAAAGATTTTTTCTCATAA

>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00029 hypothetical protein
ATGAGGTTTGCTATGCATTGGGAAGTTTTAACGATGACAAAATCAAAACGTTGGAGACCT
GTTCCAACCGTTACTAAATTTGACACAGAGCAAGAAGCTATAGACTTTAAAAACTCTCTT
AAACAATATTGTGAACTTTACCAAGTTAATGGTTAA
```

The above will also work if the input contains multiple contiguous records containing `CadC`, eg.:

```
$ cat file.ffn
>CPMPPENI_00027 hypothetical protein
this

>CPMPPENI_00028 Cadmium resistance transcriptional regulatory protein CadC
that

>foo CadC
stuff

>bar CadC
other stuff

>CPMPPENI_00029 hypothetical protein
etc.
```

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' -v OFS='|' '
    $1 ~ /CadC/ { if (!f) prt(prev); prt($0); f=1; next }
    f { prt($0); f=0 }
    { prev=$0 }
    function prt(rec) { sub(/^>/,"",rec); print ">" FILENAME, rec }
' file.ffn
>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00027 hypothetical protein
this

>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00028 Cadmium resistance transcriptional regulatory protein CadC
that

>file.ffn|foo CadC
stuff

>file.ffn|bar CadC
other stuff

>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00029 hypothetical protein
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using awk (as you tried).

**First**, save this code in `myprogram.awk` file.

```
BEGIN{myflag=0}
{
#flag=0 any line analized
#flag=1 found
#flag=-1 two consecutive lines not contains CadC
#print "ROW:"$0 "NR:"NR
    switch (myflag) {
        case "0":
                if ($0 ~ /CadC/){
                    #print "previous HEADER line:",">"FILENAME"|"myprevious; THERE IS NOT PREVIOUS RECORD
                    print FILENAME"|"$0 #print the current line
                    myflag=1 
                    next # go to next record and print it and case 1
            }
            else{
                myflag=-1
                myprevious=$0
                #print "%%%% NOT CONTAINS FIRST TIME %%%"
            }
            break
        case "1": #print the next record
            myflag=0;
            #print "NEXT LINE:"">"FILENAME"|"$0
            print FILENAME"|"$0
            break
        case "-1": #two consecutives lines not contins CadC. Then print previous line and save current line.
            if ($0 ~ /CadC/){
                print FILENAME"|"myprevious; #print previous
                print FILENAME"|"$0 #print the current line
                myflag=1
                next # go to next record and print it in case 1
            
            }else{
                print myprevious #print previous found
                myprevious=$0
            }
            break
    }

}
END{if(myflag==-1){print myprevious} 
#print NR
}
```

**Second**, execute it using this line:

```
awk -vRS=">" -vORS=">"  -f myprogram.awk file.ffn
```

You'll get this output:

```
>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00027 hypothetical protein
ATGATAAATACAATAATTACTGGAATAATTCTTTATGCAGGAACTGCAGTTGATTTAATA
ATTATTTTAATGATATTTTTTGCTAAGCTAAAAAAGAAAGATGAAATTAGACAAATTTAT
TTAGGACAATTTCTTGGATCTGGATTTCTAATTTTTTTAAGCATGATTTTCGCATATCTT
CTCCATTTTGTACCCAATAAAGAACTTTTAGGGTTATTAGGTTTAGTTCCAATTTTTTTG
GGTCTAAAAGTACTTTTAGGTGGCGAAGAGGGTGGCGAGGAATTGGCAAATGAACGCCTA
GAACAGCCTAAAAAGATCAATATCGTTTATACTTTAGCTATGATCACAGCAGTAAGTTGT
GGAGCTGATAATATTGGGTTGTTTGTTCCTTATTTCATAACTTTAAATTTTCAAAAACTA
ATTGTAACTTTAATTACTTTCTTTGTTATGATTTTCTTGCTGGTTTATTCGGCACAAAAA
ATAGTTAACTTACCAAAAATCGGAGAATTCTTAGAAAAAAATAGTAGGTGGTTTATTTCA
ATAGTATATATTGTTTTAGGTATATTCATCCTAATTGAAAATAACTCCATTGAATTATTT
AAAACCCTATTTTAA
>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00028 Cadmium resistance transcriptional regulatory protein CadC
ATGACTAAAGAATTAATTTGCGAAAATATTGTAATCGAAGAAGAAAAAGTTAACAGAGTG
TTAGATTATTTTGAAATGGATTCTTCTAAAAGGTATTTGAGAATACTTTCAAAAATAAGT
GATGAAAAGAAAGTAAAAATAATACTATCACTAATAAAAGAAGAAAAACTTTGTGTTTGT
GATGTAGCCTTTCTTCTAAATATTAGTATAGCTTCAGCGTCACATCATTTACGAAAGTTA
TATAAACAAGATGTTTTAGATTTTTCCAAAGACGGTAAAATGGTTTACTATTTTATAAAA
GATGATGAAATAAAAGATTTTTTCTCATAA
>file.ffn|CPMPPENI_00029 hypothetical protein
ATGAGGTTTGCTATGCATTGGGAAGTTTTAACGATGACAAAATCAAAACGTTGGAGACCT
GTTCCAACCGTTACTAAATTTGACACAGAGCAAGAAGCTATAGACTTTAAAAACTCTCTT
AAACAATATTGTGAACTTTACCAAGTTAATGGTTAA
```

I hope is what you need.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for `switch` statements and to not have a space after each `-v`. `if ($0 ~ /CadC/)` can be written as just `if (/CadC/)` btw.